# search on name and special char in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am searching on names in some names it has special char(&,(),').
    my index  mapping look like this

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "analyzer_startswith": {
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": "lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

  "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "namefeild": {
                    "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want search the name 'you & me' .

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_phrase_prefix":{"namefeild":"you & me"}}}]}},"from":0,"size":100}
```

Here when i search name till 'you &' i get result after me i get result null.
    Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me for "you &" and "you & me"

if this still not working for you,please post the exact query which is returning null results

```
PUT sf
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "analyzer_startswith": {
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": "lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

  "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "namefeild": {
                    "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


POST sf/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
  "text":     "you &"
}


POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "sf", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "1" } }
{"namefeild": "you" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "sf", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "2" } }
{"namefeild": "you & me" }


GET sf/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                    "namefeild": "you & me"
                }
            }
        ]}
    }
```

Comment: Please provide exact set of commands you are using? What is your version of ES?